# jQuery/JS : empty field after success?

Tags: javascript, jquery

at my ajax call success i wish to empty the field.

```
   success: function(msg){
     $(wrapperId).prepend(msg);
    }
 }
```

I tried this:

```
   success: function(msg){
     $(wrapperId).prepend(msg);
     $('#message').html("");
    }
 }
```

But it wont work

Comment: *Which* field are you trying to empty?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#message').val("");
```